# HTML5 Canvas Save Drawing as an Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a question about saving the png to the canvas. 
It saves me a picture, but it saves me just what draws. As I loaded the background that no longer sees.

```
var dataURL = this.canva.toDataURL();
document.getElementById(id).src = dataURL;
```

background images I have written out so

```
 function leapController()
        {
            var tracks = new Array();
            tracks[0] = {link: 'png/1.png'};
            tracks[1] = {link: 'png/2.png'};
            tracks[2] = {link: 'png/3.png'};
            tracks[3] = {link: 'png/4.png'};
            tracks[4] = {link: 'png/5.png'};
```

I would like to enroll my whole image, along with the background and drawing element

Comment: Backgrounds are not exported with `.toDataURL`. To also get the background, first draw the background in the canvas with `drawImage`.

Comment: ok i understand and help me change it?

Comment: if someone is able to me to change the tracks on canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You give precious little code in your question, but the idea is when you're ready to save the canvas you can use Compositing to draw the background image **behind the existing pixels**.

To get you started ... here's some code applying the idea:

```
function save(desiredBackgroundIndex){

    // set context compositing to draw behind existing pixels
    context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';

    // Draw the desired background on the canvas BEHIND existing pixels
    // Assumes tracks[] is in scope
    context.drawImage(tracks[desiredBackgroundIndex],0,0);

    // always clean up! Change compositing mode back to default
    context.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';

    // set #id's src to the canvas's data url
    document.getElementById(id).src = this.canva.toDataURL();

}

// USAGE example: add png/3.png to the canvas and save the canvas's data url to #id
save(2);
```